# Port Removal from Ireland and ILR Application in the UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, ireland, removal

I'm an Irish citizen - my girlfriend and I live in London. Last Christmas we tried to go to Ireland on the boat, but my girlfriend didn't have her passport with her (she is not an EU citizen). The Immigration team at the port stopped her and sent her back on the boat as she didn't have the right documents. They gave her a 2-page document: 1st page was to the Ship Company - a Carrier's Removal Direction under section 5(10)(b) of the Immigration Act 2003, and the 2nd page: Addressed to her under the Immigration Act(g) 'that the non-national is not in possession of a valid passport or other equivalent document, issued by or on behalf of an authority recognised by the Government, which establishes his or her identity and nationality.' She has had Tourist Visas to Ireland twice before and the Immigration guy said it was not a big deal. But, she is trying to apply for a Tourist Visa again and one of the questions asks about removal from a port in Ireland.

Does anyone know if we can check to see if this removal has been recorded in the system? Is there any phone number to ring or place to check?

If it is in the system, does anyone know if this will possibly result in a rejection of the Tourist visa?

Can anyone give any advice please - we are worried to apply as a rejection might affect her UK and other travel Visas.

If it is a rejection, does this mean that she won't be allowed to Ireland again?

Also, most importantly she will apply for Indefinite visa in the UK in February.
Any idea if this situation effects her ILR visa application?

Comment: Come along, do you seriously think they issued a removal notice without putting it in the system?  The rest of your question relies upon her status in the UK at the time and her nationality, which you didn't tell us.  Close voting as 'unclear'. Please edit to include all the info.

Comment: Hi, She is from Turkey and she has self-employed visa. She is eligible to apply for her ILR in February.Please let me know what else you need to know. Thanks.

Comment: Got it, I don't see it being much of an issue. the Turkish Businessperson Visa is a very niche area and questions for or about people in that category are for the Expats site. I will ask the moderators to migrate this automatically so it should appear there ready for answers within a few hours.

Comment: @MarkMayo, flagged for migration

Comment: Wait, so the IO told you that it wasn't a big deal being turned back. Implying that there shouldn't be any problem with future applications, Yet you're still apparently considering lying by omission about it on a future application, which is a **huge** deal, and will have massive negative consequences on all future applications to anywhere that shares information with the Irish authorities? Think *very* carefully about your next steps.

Comment: @Nhr I reopened it to move to expatriates.stackexchange.com, but it's really not fit for it yet. You've asked several questions in one, and it's not entirely clear what you're after (as per some of the comments).  What I'd suggest you do is go to expatriates.stackexchange.com and ask there, but ask one question at a time - you're far more likely to get an answer. Include all relevant information about citizenship, departments, types of visas and events - the more useful info, the more likely to get an answer.  Remember to read the [help] as well.

Comment: Hi, I am the gf. Thanks for your answers. Yes, that was what IO said by the time but I dont want to risk it and not applying visa to Ireland because of my indefinite application in the UK.My biggest worry is my ILR Application at the mo.I talked to my lawyer and he said it wont effect my ILR because its a different case but I dont really trust his knowledge about this area.That's why I am searching bymyself.

Comment: @GayotFow not migrating as it's not in a state fit for migration - I'd have to migrate and then immediately close on expats.  See above comment for how I hope they'll proceed.

Comment: In ILR form there is no question about any removal or anything but i am worried it might come under Good Character. I read guides and they only mention about coming to UK without valid documents not really other countries so I dont know if it effects me or not. I would appreciate if anyone can give me some advice.Thanks

Comment: Ok Mark Mayo thanks. I have just seen your message.